# Visual Studio Solution Explorer Keeps showing nuget packages I am no longer referencing

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have tried to replace the RazorEngine nuget package with the RazorEngineCore one to avoid the vulnerability that affects RazorEngine, unfortunately I have had some dependencies issues, so I have decided to roll back the change to look for another package.

However, even when I have restored the .csproj file and removed all the existing changes in the repository, the Solution Explorer keeps showing me the RazorEngineCore and not the RazorEngine in the dependencies. If I go to the Nuget Package Manager it shows me that the RazorEngie is installed and the RazorEngineCore is not, as I would expect.

I would like to fix the issue in the Solution Explorer, I have tried to unload the project and load again with dependencies but that has not worked.

The .csproj file is showing this reference:

```
<PackageReference Include="RazorEngine">
  <Version>3.10.0</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

Comment: Can you please show your .csproj?

Comment: What will the explorer look like if install both?

Comment: Did you already try deleting the bin and obj folders and try a clean rebuild after replacing the nugets?

Comment: After deleting the bin folder and rebuilding the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ewerspej said.
You try deleting bin and obj folders and try doing a clean rebuild after replacing nugets.

The bin directory is used to store the assembly after the project is built.

The obj directory is used to save the compilation results of each module. Hope it can help you.